# Development environment DistributedCache.RoutingClient error

Tags: c#, azure

I'm having an issue that seems to frequently occur in the middle of my development environment.

```
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : ERROR: <DistributedCache.RoutingClient> e4600bc4-bf61-47d7-afb6-cc265b30ff07:SendMsgAndWait: Request TimedOut, msgId = 527
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : ERROR: <DistributedCache.RoutingClient> 493e6310-08db-48d0-bc38-767ad14d7dce:SendMsgAndWait: Request TimedOut, msgId = 528
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : ERROR: <DistributedCache.RoutingClient> 9a9613c0-4459-45b8-8986-ff0a779f532f:SendMsgAndWait: Request TimedOut, msgId = 536
iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : ERROR: <DistributedCache.RoutingClient> 0732f7e8-58b5-4ab1-b506-e65b138e296d:SendMsgAndWait: Request TimedOut, msgId = 535
```

Are the messages that show up in my Debug of Visual Studio 2012. What will happen is my testing of a ASP.Net Webform will halt while this error is going on and for a short term fix I break my debugging and reenter debugging. Searching around for this type of error has not yielded any successful results and/or fixes, some insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did my own search and I found those related forum posts:

- [Windows Azure Caching while debugging - Request Timeout](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/262681e4-7922-4d24-950a-ba0cac50994f/windows-azure-caching-while-debugging-request-timeout?forum=windowsazuredata).
- [While Debugging: ERROR: `<DistributedCache.RoutingClient>` SendMsgAndWait: Request TimedOut](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47a384df-f464-44a3-91ec-d929008112b2/while-debugging-error-distributedcacheroutingclient-sendmsgandwait-request-timedout?forum=windowsazuredata)

You are using WebForm, though these are solutions within Azure, they should help you with finding a fix.

Also, make sure you are using your computers cache.

Here is a link for AppFabric Caching: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx

Hope this helps!